# How to quote first row only when writing R .csv files

Tags: r, csv

I'm new to R, and trying to export a data.frame as a csv file, but the first row contains strings that need to be quoted, where the rest of the data is numeric (but with NA as some options to be written as "NA") and shouldn't be quoted.  My code is:

```
class(mt.collapsed) <- 'numeric';
write.csv(mt.collapsed, 'NI_mtVars_phenoFile_161212.dat', row.names = T, quote = F)
```

My question is: How do I write the matrix as mentioned above in the appropriate manner?

I had thought of popping off the first row and saving that with "quote = T", and then write as append all rows except the first row with "quote = F".  This seems a bit amateurish to me.

Thanks

So, >900 columns, here's the first 3 columns, but other than column #1 being an id (as row.name) all other columns are in the same format/style as below.

Sorry ... not having luck formatting this into a table:

```
id      00010;T;C   00025;AC;A  
X110020 1           2   
X110030 1           2   
X110050 1           2   
X110150 1           NA
```

The output for :

```
    > str(mt.collapsed[, 1:3]) 
num [1:678, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... 
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2 
..$ : chr [1:678] "X110020" "X110030" "X110050" "X110080" ... 
..$ : chr [1:3] "00010;T;C" "00025;AC;A" "00044;C;CG"
```

Comment: What does your matrix look like? Can you just use column names instead of the first row? Setting the class doesn't necessarily make it so... you could introduce `NA`s via the conversion. Showing `head(mt.collapsed)` (and maybe `str(mt.collapsed)` would provide good information.

Comment: The first row has "id" as the first cell, a code for the next ~900 columns like "00065;C;T" (it is a phenotype data file for GenABEL import),

Comment: Posting `head(mt.collapsed)` and `str(mt.collapsed)` would provide good information. **Please edit those results into your question.**

Comment: We need to understand your data structures to help you. You say you have "a matrix", but after posting your data that seems unlikely. Looks like a `data.frame`? Are those `row.names` or an actual data column? Please post `str(mt.collapsed[, 1:3])`.

Comment: Please edit it into your question and format it as code (do the same for the table) to make things more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the first row as the column names of the matrix?  The code:

```
foo = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ncol = 2)
colnames(foo) = c("a", "b")
```

gives the following matrix with named columns.

```
     a b
[1,] 1 4
[2,] 2 5
[3,] 3 6
```

Then, when you write it to a .csv file:

```
write.csv(foo, "foo.csv", row.names = F)
```

the file contains:

```
"a","b"
1,4
2,5
3,6
```